# how to load the image having negative height

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am working on a Win32 sample application in which I am loading image and displaying then on the screen.
To load the image I am using the LoadImage(). This will return the proper result for some of the image. So some of the image it is failing with error 8.

Then I came to know that if the height of the image is –ve then it is getting failed. If the image height is –ve then image is upside down.

Please let me know how to load the image having –ve height

Comment: from 22 to 25th byte of the image gives us the height of the bitmap. There the value is –ve (0XFFFFFEF3).

Comment: By `-ve`, you mean `negative`?

Comment: Then please use that word. As for your question, a negative height doesn't even start to make sense for a bitmap. Where did you get them from? Can you fix them?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format, In this link they have mentioned that image height can be negative. (search for the word "negative" in the above link.)

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/77127

Comment: @Mat In WIndows BMP file the height specified in the header can be negative: it means that the image is stored from bottom to top. When the height is positive then the image is stored from top to bottom.

Comment: @Mat: For someone with so much reputation I am surprised you did not know that.

Comment: @graham.reeds: lol. Do you think knowing the specs of Microsoft bitmaps is an absolute essential for any software dev? (I don't code GUI stuff on windows at all.)

Comment: @Mat: Well I knew remembered that (negative heights) from the last time I did any image work in the GDI which was about 8 years ago.  Also I think if you look in Principles and Practive (Foley, Van Dam, et al) you will find an interesting discussion on why it may be faster.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft bitmaps are usually stored from bottom to top.

When the height in the bitmap header is negative then it means that the image is stored from top to bottom, and its real height is abs(height specified in the header).

If you use GDI functions they take care of this (they display the image correctly, starting from the bottom if the height is positive or from the top if the height is negative).